# Manipulating WPF elements via vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm in the process of transitioning from a project in vb6 to vb .net and WPF.
In the old project, there are various functions which change the UI (hide buttons) given the user permissions.

How do you do the same in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the visibility of a button in the code behind(the .vb file) the syntax is:

```
button.Visibility = [Windows.Visibility.Collapsed, Windows.Visibility.Hidden, Windows.Visibility.Visible]
```

In the XAML the syntax is:

```
<Button Name="Button" Visibility="[Hidden, Collapsed, Visible]" />
```

Windows.Visibility.Collapsed - The element is hidden from the user and any space that the element would have taken up is released so that elements lower down the UI will move up to fill the space

Windows.Visibility.Hidden - The element is hidden from the user but the space is still occupied as if the element were visible.

Windows.Visibility.Visible - The element is visible to the user.